# Is there a way to operate and do calculations with the numbers between data gaps?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I would like to do certain operations between groups of data in the same row. I have data from a device into Excel. This data gives me the time on the position of certain object on a screen. But there are some fragments of data missing due to noise of the instrument among others.

Is there a way to operate and do calculations with the numbers between these data gaps?

For example:

[image: Example data SO12078075]

```
 Cell   Time    Position                   
 ----   ------  --------- ------------- 
 1      0.05 s   12.3  mm                    
 2      0.10 s   12    mm                      
 3      0.15 s   13    mm                      
 4      0.20 s   13.33 mm                   
 5      0.28 s    0    mm (data missing)  
 6      0.30 s    0    mm                       
 7      0.36 s   14.21 mm
```

So, in the next column I want to have the final position - the initial position (overall object movement). and I want Excel to find the `0` and subtract the cell above from the first one. In the example it would be `13.33`-`12.30` and I want to do the same for the next set of data starting with `14.21 mm` (until it reaches another `0`).

Comment: there might be a way, but you should present your problem in a better way - such problems are far more understandable, when you post a source-table (how data looks now) and a target-table (how you would like the data to look like)

Comment: oh. sorry i meant cell 3 (in the 3rd cell). So, cell 3 - 0.15s 13 mm. Sorry abou the explanation but it is really complicatet to put it down in words.